# error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html

estoy utilizando datatables en una representación de datos que tienen que cambiar estado dependiendo de lo que responda el webservice consultado entonces a veces el dato no esta en la pestaña que esta representada en ese momento, entonces me da ese error porque pues no esta el id, lo que quiero saber si hay alguna manera de manejar este error y tambien cuando le asigno las propiedades a la celda no me toma todo el codigo solo la parte de la imagen

```
document.getElementById(cont).innerHTML='<img src="img/bullet-red.png" class="tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="Sin Peso">';
```

Comment: este problema me ha pasado de otra manera, sin menos aderesos... lo que pasa es que no puedes actualizar un datatable que no es visible; te recomiendo que solo actualices los datos de la TAB visisble; cuando cambias de una datatable a otro debes tambien hacer un re-redenrizado con `.draw()`

Comment: que tal mi amigo gracias por tu respuesta, estoy corriendo mi servicio luego del renderizado, ahora lo que no puedo hacer es obtener los datos del tab visible me puede ayudar con eso por favor ?

Comment: agace otro post